# Geometry vs. BufferGeometry best practice for new projects? (r68)

Tags: three.js

I've read a lot of comments on BufferGeometry and Geometry.
Most of the comments are from February 2014. But I don't know if they are still correct.

As far as I understand the comments, BufferGeometry should be faster, less memory hungry, and less user friendly.

I made some tests with the project I am working on, and I couldn't confirm these claims.
I used ThreeJS r68.
I created 9 Objects each with 12,000 faces. I tested speed and memory usage with: Geometry, BufferGeometry and BufferGeometry(dynamic = true).
The memory usage was always ~650 MB. 
The speed was always ~90 FPS. (or ~340FPS on a different computer)
I could only confirm the less user friendly ;)

With iOS8 (releasing tomorrow?) and the goal to get my application to work on tablets, my question is:

Should I use Geometry or BufferGeometry?  Or did ThreeJS develop so fast since February 2014 that there is no difference anymore, because in reality Geometry is just a front end for BufferGeometry?

best regards 
Benedikt

Answer (score 1):

If BufferGeometry meets your needs, use it. It will be faster and less memory-hungry.